# unlink() is not working

Tags: php, html, linux, unlink

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['list']); $i++) { 
            echo $_POST['list'][$i]; 
            if(is_file($_POST['list'][$i])) echo "ok"; else echo "false";
            unlink($_POST['list'][$i]);
       }
```

I am trying to delete image file in my server.

`echo $_POST['list'][$i]` outputs `../Profile/JPN012/test2.JPG`(route of image).

BUT `is_file()` and `unlink()` are not working.
Though I changed permission of all directory and image `file(0777)`, it doesn't work.

(Linux OS environment)

What's the problem??

Comment: Check case and check if the relative path is correct. You'd be safer with an absolute path.

Comment: What kind of error are showing ? would you kindly add your error

Comment: the page shows nothing( just white screen). I tried with an absolute path though, it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your file path argument in is_file and unlink. If you can change directory to where the file is located before call is_file or unlink, it would be easier. After that, you can use only filename like is_file('test2.png').

```
   <?php
    $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
    chdir($path_to_file);
    unlink($filename);
    chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory    
   ?>
```

(source: https://www.php.net/chdir)

Comment: I think I almost solve this problem, but I get one obstacle. unlink("test.jpg"); is working but unlink($_POST['list'][$i]); is not working($_POST['list'][$i] is the name of file e.g test.jpg), which means that hard coding is sort of working though, the other is not....

Comment: i think you need to check $_POST['list'][$i] output. Does it only display file name? you need also taking care of whitespace begin and end of the test

Answer (score 0):

check path in the server, it most likely to be

```
$compositefilename = PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_ROOT . "/composite/" . $compositeresult;
```